# Querying PostgreSQL using WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I have created a table called Markers. Below is the .sql file.

```
CREATE TABLE markers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
    ip_address varchar(25),
    Hostname varchar(255),
    Continent varchar(255),
    Country varchar(255),
    Capital varchar(255),
    State varchar (255),
    City_Location varchar(255)
);
```

I have a text file which contains ip addresses. The file looks like this.

```
8.8.8.8
23.64.0.0
31.0.0.0
50.22.0.0
54.244.0.0
54.72.0.0
54.80.0.0
```

The information belonging to each IP address is stored in the table.
If I want to gather data for ip 8.8.8.8, I can write a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM markers WHERE ip_address='8.8.8.8';
```

and similarly I can do for other IP. But this is time consuming since I have to write a query for each IP address.

Instead, is there any way that I can read the IP address from text file and execute the query for all IP addresses in one shot?

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can't do that with postgres alone. Just write a script (in any language you like) that will read the file and execute the query.

Comment: Doesnt answer the question but you might be interested in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-net-types.html

Comment: @freakish I am using BASH script. Is it possible to do with BASH? Or should I go with php ?

Comment: @SwateshPakhare It certainly is possible to do it in bash. Something like pipeing `cat` line by line to `psql`. I don't recommend using php for that. Python would be a nice alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using psql and issuing the following commands (tailor to your particular case, reading PG manual on "COPY FROM"):

```
create temp table ip_addresses (ip_address text);
copy ip_addresses from stdin csv; -- pipe your text file here
select * from markers where ip_address in (select * from ip_addresses);
```

Comment: Can I do this without using a text file ?

Comment: I figured out how to do it without using text file. I replaced the second line of your code with this `copy ip_addresses from PROGRAM ' #your commands ';`